# Iterating MovingMap with Nest

Tags: list-manipulation, iteration

I am trying to create a background correction inspired by the [PyMca strip background method](http://pymca.sourceforge.net/stripbackground.html). The data I'm trying to correct is a HPLC chromatogram in the form of a `TimeSeries` (named normalizedchromatogram in this case). The idea is to generate a background through iterations of `Mean` and `MovingMap` with a windows size dependent on the `MinimumTimeIncrement` of said `TimeSeries`.
A code snippet thats already working as intended:

```
MovingMap[Mean, normalizedchromatogram, {10*MinimumTimeIncrement[normalizedchromatogram], Center}, "Fixed"]
```

However, I don't know how to iterate this snippet now. It seems to me, that using `Nest` would be a suitable approach to iterate the code, but `Nest` doesn't allow for using my code snippet above as a function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try: `MovingMap[Mean, # , ...] &`

Comment: Thank you very much Mr. Huber, that did the trick. However, I'm seeing now that my approach is not sophisticated enough for actually generating a reasonable background. Mathematicas own `EstimatedBackground` delivers much better results.